Code error when trying to create CNN neural network using gabor filters and K means algorithm for method of data enhancement
goal of code is to combine Gabor filters, K means algorithm, with CNN neural network as a way of processing method of data enhancement but it doesn't work what do I need to do?

import tensorflow as tf

assert tf.version.VERSION.startswith("2.")

tf.keras.layers
tf.keras.models
tf.keras.preprocessing

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image_dataset_from_directory
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model
import cv2
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

dataset_path = "/content/drive/Shareddrives/Internship data sets/dataset"

batch_size = 32
img_height = 256
img_width = 256

train_ds = image_dataset_from_directory(
    dataset_path,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="training",
    seed=123,
    image_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size
)

val_ds = image_dataset_from_directory(
    dataset_path,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="validation",
    seed=123,
    image_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size
)

def make_paired_dataset(dataset):
    X_pairs, y_pairs = [], []

    for batch in dataset:
        images, labels = batch
        for i in range(len(images)):
            for j in range(len(images)):
                img_A, label_A = images[i], labels[i]
                img_B, label_B = images[j], labels[j]
                new_label = int(label_A == label_B)
                X_pairs.append([img_A.numpy(), img_B.numpy()])
                y_pairs.append(new_label)

    X_pairs = np.array(X_pairs)
    y_pairs = np.array(y_pairs)

    return X_pairs, y_pairs

X_train_pairs, y_train_pairs = make_paired_dataset(train_ds)
X_test_pairs, y_test_pairs = make_paired_dataset(val_ds)

print(X_train_pairs.shape, y_train_pairs.shape)
print(X_test_pairs.shape, y_test_pairs.shape)

def gabor_filter_layer(img_height, img_width):
    def gabor_filter(x):
        x = tf.reshape(x, (-1, img_height, img_width))
        x = tf.expand_dims(x, axis=-1)
        gabor_filter = tf.constant(cv2.getGaborKernel((img_height, img_width), 4, np.pi/4, 10, 0.5), dtype=tf.float32)
        gabor_filter = gabor_filter[:, :, tf.newaxis, tf.newaxis]
        x = tf.nn.conv2d(x, gabor_filter, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
        x = tf.squeeze(x, axis=-1)
        return x

    return tf.keras.layers.Lambda(gabor_filter)

def kmeans_clustering_layer(n_clusters):
    def kmeans_clustering(x):
        x = tf.reshape(x, (-1, img_height * img_width))
        output = tf.py_function(func=lambda inp: tf.one_hot(KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters).fit(inp.numpy().reshape(-1, inp.shape[1])).labels_, depth=n_clusters),
                              inp=[x],
                              Tout=tf.float32,
                              name='kmeans_pyfunc')
        output.set_shape((x.shape[0], n_clusters))
        return output

    return tf.keras.layers.Lambda(kmeans_clustering)

def kmeans_clustering(inp):
    def clustering(inp):
        kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4)
        labels = kmeans.fit(tf.reshape(inp, (-1, inp.shape[1]))).labels_
        return tf.one_hot(labels, depth=4)
    output = tf.py_function(clustering, [inp], tf.float32)
    output = tf.squeeze(output, axis=0)
    output.set_shape((256, 256, 4))
    return output

img_A_inp = Input((img_height * img_width), name='img_A_inp')
img_B_inp = Input((img_height * img_width), name='img_B_inp')

img_A_inp = Input((256, 256, 512), name='img_A_inp')
img_B_inp = Input((256, 256, 512), name='img_B_inp')

gabor_layer = gabor_filter_layer(img_height, img_width)
gabor_A = gabor_layer(img_A_inp)
gabor_B = gabor_layer(img_B_inp)

kmeans_layer = Lambda(kmeans_clustering)
kmeans_A = kmeans_layer(gabor_A)
kmeans_B = kmeans_layer(gabor_B)

concat_A = Concatenate(axis=-1)([tf.reshape(kmeans_A, (-1, img_height, img_width, 4))])
concat_B = Concatenate(axis=-1)([tf.reshape(kmeans_B, (-1, img_height, img_width, 4))])

def get_cnn_block(depth):
  return Sequential([Conv2D(depth, 3, 1),
                     BatchNormalization(),
                     ReLU()])

DEPTH = 64
cnn = Sequential([get_cnn_block(DEPTH),
                  get_cnn_block(DEPTH*2),
                  get_cnn_block(DEPTH*4),
                  get_cnn_block(DEPTH*8),
                  GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
                  Dense(64, activation='relu')])

feature_vector_A = cnn(concat_A)
feature_vector_B = cnn(concat_B)

concat = Concatenate()([feature_vector_A, feature_vector_B])

dense = Dense(64, activation='relu')(concat)
output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(dense)

model = Model(inputs=[img_A_inp, img_B_inp], outputs=output)

import numpy as np

y_train_pairs_repeated = np.repeat(y_train_pairs, 2)
print(y_train_pairs_repeated.shape)

model.summary()
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

es = EarlyStopping(patience=3)

X_train_A = X_train_A.reshape(-1, 256, 256)
X_train_B = X_train_B.reshape(-1, 256, 256)
X_test_A = X_test_A.reshape(-1, 256, 256)
X_test_B = X_test_B.reshape(-1, 256, 256)

X_train_input = np.concatenate((X_train_A, X_train_B), axis=-1)
X_test_input = np.concatenate((X_test_A, X_test_B), axis=-1)

y_train_pairs_repeated = np.repeat(y_train_pairs, 3, axis=0)
y_test_pairs_repeated = np.repeat(y_test_pairs, 3, axis=0)


img_A_inp = Input((256, 256, 512), name='img_A_inp')
img_B_inp = Input((256, 256, 512), name='img_B_inp')

x = concatenate([img_A_inp, img_B_inp], axis=-1)
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)

model = Model(inputs=[img_A_inp, img_B_inp], outputs=x)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])


history = model.fit(x={'img_A_inp': X_train_A, 'img_B_inp': X_train_B},
                    y=y_train_pairs_repeated,
                    validation_data=({'img_A_inp': X_test_A, 'img_B_inp': X_test_B}, y_test_pairs_repeated),
                    epochs=1000, batch_size=32, callbacks=[es])

Basically when I try to run the code starting from history = model.fit, this many errors come up, and I've asked AI to help me fix it, but instead of fixing it, it has mainly just made it worse, can someone tell me what is wrong? Thanks

Hello, welcome to StackOverflow, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, notably the section "Help others reproduce the problem". Your post is not minimal. Your code should be narrowed. Use data with random value, so everyone can run it and the dimension will be respected, remove all EarlyStop. Plus post in a different blockquote the errors. Eventually, write your dependencies, notably the tensorflow, sklearn and opencv versions. Good luck!
